# Veracrypt encrypted file - how to expand the Volume

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

If you have created an encrypted file but the volume which you selected for it needs expansion, is it from security standpoint fine to just use the available option "expand volume" to adjust the file's volume?  Or is it for some reason better to create a totally new encrypted file with your desired larger volume?

Comment: I can't think of any issues for #1, is there something in particular you are worried will happen?

Comment: Apparently not all of the question was migrated?

Answer (score 5):

Veracrypt for Linux doesn’t have an “*expand volume*”. This seems to be Windows only and from some quick googling may have significant reliability issues. I would suggest making a backup before trying this. If you have the space to make a backup, it might be easier and more reliable to simply make a new bigger container and move the files across.

The Drive Letters (A-Z) are mount points for Windows. Veracrypt does not care what letter you use.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old, old post but, in case this can help anyone, I used the steps to expand the container I had and had an issue. I used Tools, expand Volume and followed the steps and it seemed to work well. I mounted the container and the VeraCrypt console showed I mounted a 2.0TB container. However, when I opened it up in explorer, it still showed it as being 1.0TB. I went to see if I could expand it in Computer Management - Disk Management, but it was not there, so I could not do that. After 30 minutes, I opted to just create a new 2.0TB container and move everything over. Just FYI

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160075)

Comment: Bernardo, for me it was exactly the same. Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, the volume expansion for VeraCrypt seems to work exclusively for spherical chickens on a vacuum...